# Printing a vector with cat function in R - How to avoid losing element names

Tags: r, printing

I am creating a print method in `R` for objects of a particular class, using the steps set out in [this article](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/s3-class/).  As part of this task, I want to print a vector with the `cat` function, while still including the names of its elements (with the nice spacing you normally get under standard printing).  However, when I try to do this, the function eliminates the element names.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Create a named vector
VECTOR <- c(12.5, 16.8, 10.1, 14.0)
names(VECTOR) <- c('Harry', 'Jennifer', 'Milton', 'Susan')
class(VECTOR) <- 'MyNewClass'

#Print vector using default printing (including names)
VECTOR

#Create new print method
print.MyNewClass <- function(object) {
  cat('I want to print this text, and then print the vector nicely \n \n')
  cat(object, '\n \n') }

#Print vector using new print method
VECTOR

#Restore default printing
rm(print.MyNewClass)
```

Under the default print call (using default printing) the vector is displayed with the names of the elements, and with nice spacing:

```
   Harry Jennifer   Milton    Susan 
    12.5     16.8     10.1     14.0 
attr(,"class")
[1] "MyNewClass"
```

Under the new print method (designed using the `cat` function) the vector is displayed without the names of its elements:

```
I want to print this text, and then print this vector nicely 

12.5 16.8 10.1 14
```

I can try to add the element names in manually, but it is complicated to do this in a way that gets the spacing correct.  Thus, I am wondering if there is a simple method to use the `cat` function (or some other function) to print the vector with the names of its elements included.

Comment: Why not use the default print if it gives what you want?

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the code for `print.default`, which would be handling numeric vectors. `ts <- 1:10;names(ts) <- paste0("Number ", 1:10);print.default(ts)`. The code can be printed simply executing `print.default`. Outside using `pairlist` and internal functions you will likely find it rather tedious to force width of prinout.

Comment: As a side note, if you check `print` functions for various classes, they often utilize functions such as `printCoefmat` to print output from functions.

Comment: @Dason: I do not want default printing - I want to add other textual elements before printing the vector (with the names of its elements, but without other attributes).

Comment: Do **not** end instructions with a semi-colon, this is R not C. `instruction;` is in fact **2** instructions, since in R `;` is the instruction separator. The second is the `NULL` instruction.

Comment: @Ben I still don't see why you couldn't utilize print.default in your own print function. If you could provide some example input and how you would like it to display that would help.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Can you elaborate further - why is the use of the semicolon bad?

Comment: @Dason: Okay, now I understand - that is a good suggestion.

Comment: Because it separates instructions, it does not mark the end of instructions. `instr1;` is **2** instructions: `instr1;NULL`. Likewise, `instr1;instr2;` is **3** instructions: `instr1;instr;NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to do it with `cat` but to get the behavior you're looking for, you could do remove the `class` within your `print.MyNewClass` S3 method:

```
#Create new print method
print.MyNewClass <- function(object) {
  
  # Your original cat
  cat('I want to print this text, and then print the vector nicely \n \n')
  
  # Remove class from object
  # Removes `attr(,"class")` from print
  attr(object, which = "class") <- NULL
  
  # Print
  print(object)
  
  # Add space (like you had previously)
  cat("\n\n")
  
}

#Print vector using new print method
VECTOR
```

Here's the output:

```
> VECTOR
I want to print this text, and then print the vector nicely 
 
   Harry Jennifer   Milton    Susan 
    12.5     16.8     10.1     14.0
```

Comment: For posterity: `unclass(object)` is simpler and more straightforward than `attr(object, which = "class") <- NULL`